# How to fix the problem, I want it to be lined up and not staggered or repeat

Tags: java, arrays, string, unicode, char

trying to put unicode value next to corresponding char. I already made the string into a char and to unicode I just want to be able to print both the char array and the unicode next to one another

```
public class StringToChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String str= "javadla";



        char[] charArray=str.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ ) {
            int retval = str.codePointAt(i);
        for (char c : charArray) {
            System.out.println(c+ ":"+ (retval));
```

should be something like

j:106
   a:97
   v:118
   a:97
   d:100
   l:108
   a:97

Comment: by using System.out.print instead of System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are looping through the characters of the String, and then in the inner loop, you are again looping through the char array, which is again the characters of the same string. Because of that your expected result is printed repeatedly.

Therefore you can use a single for loop as below to go through the string and get both character and character code at the same time from the current index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "javadla";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int retVal = str.codePointAt(i);
        System.out.print(c + ":" + (retVal) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`println()` method adds a `new-line` after each statement, so if you want them all on same line use `print()` method instead.

```
System.out.print(c+ ":"+ (retval));
```